# How to create a predefined schema for Spark?

Tags: apache-spark, schema

I have a service (Secor) which writes raw messages received to parquet files. I'd like to create a predefined schema for these parquet files, so Spark will be able to combine several files with possible changes in the schema.

We're using Spark 2.1.0

**Elaborated example:**
We save data for an entire day under folders bearing the date, and under each date we have the data segregated by hour. Meaning, our parquet files look like this:

```
date=2017-03-23
   |-- hour=00
   |-- hour=01
   //
   |-- hour=23
```

let's say the schema the messages parsed to parquet contained only two fields at the beginning of the day, say:

```
root
  |-- user: String
  |-- id: Long
```

Now around mid-day, wev'e added another field, so the schema becomes:

```
root
  |-- user: String
  |-- id: Long
  |-- country: String
```

That means that if we're trying to read the data of the entire day using `sparksession.read.parquet.("s3a://bucket/date=2017-03-23")`, Spark will crash due to the fact that the sub-folders do not have the same schema. s we rarely change the schema, I prefer not to use the schema-merging option, as it's highly expensive.

**Bottom line:** What I'd like to do is to pre-define a schema and store it under `date=2017-03-23`, and so Spark will know what columns to look for, and add `null` where the column is missing. In Spark 1.6 there were `_metadata` files, but it seems that in Spark 2.1 they're no longer there.

How can I manually create these schema files for Spark?

Answer (score 0):

If you can't do it with spark, I think it's not complicated to make a class that transform a json to a schema, an then store your json file for each day.

Comment: yes, but where and how do I store it so Spark will refer to it as the schema?

Comment: you can store the file schema.json in date=2017-03-23 directory and then read it as json and tranform the json schema: exemple json {"name": "id", "type": "string"} becomes schema= StructType(Seq(StructFiel("id", StringType, true)))

Comment: that's an option, though I was hoping to find an implicit way in which Spark does it  by itself when examining the files